# Having the android resources online

Tags: android

I am trying to build a generic app where I can load all the resources from online, so that depending on the input, certain resources should be loaded. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you considered using HTML5, something like an embedded web app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to load resources like images and text from online server at runtime.
All you will have to do is to

Call your webservice

Get your resources (I guess, text and images is your requirement) from response

Inflate your layout

Set their values/resources.

EDIT:

The 3rd paragraph states that :

> For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on
>   pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it
>   is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser
>   **over a plain XML file at runtime**; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)

I didn't mentioned to create yourLayout.xml at runtime, in that case I would have been wrong.

To prove my point here is the example of one of my class from that project:

```
public class WriteScreen extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.writescreen);
        title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.writescreentitle);
        array_listaudiodurationurl=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listcreatorname=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listtype=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listurl=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listcreatorid=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listcreatoravatar=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listid=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listcontent=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listduration=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listtype1=new  ArrayList<String>();
        array_listimagetype=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listimageurl=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listurl1=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listlastmodified=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listcreated=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listmaintype=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listsource=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_listaudiourl=new ArrayList<String>();
        Intent in =getIntent();

        eId = in.getStringExtra("EventsId");
        tit=in.getStringExtra("Title");
        title.setText(tit);

        mypref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(WriteScreen.this);
        username = mypref.getString("username", "0");
        password = mypref.getString("Password", "0");


        write=(Button)findViewById(R.id.writescreenwritebtn);  
        moderate =(Button)findViewById(R.id.writescreenmoderate);
        users=(Button)findViewById(R.id.writescreenusers);

        try 
        {
            try 
            {
            writescreen();

            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {

            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writelowerparts();

    }

    public void playAudio()
    {
         if (WriteScreen.this.audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) 
            {
             WriteScreen.this.audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
            } 
            else 
            {
                WriteScreen.this.audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();
                WriteScreen.this.audioStreamer.startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
         isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    }

    public void writelowerparts() 
    {
        boolean isgrey=true;
        TableLayout  tl  = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayoutwritescreen);  
        tl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

          if (tl != null)
          {
              tl.removeAllViews();
          }
        if(array_listcreatorid.size() > 0 )
         {
          LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
          LayoutParams lpAddRow = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
          LayoutParams lpImageView = new LayoutParams(MyEvents.width - (MyEvents.width/2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

          for( i = 0; i < array_listcreatorid.size(); i++) 
          {  
            Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
            int ro = calendar.getTimeZone().getRawOffset();
            int dst = calendar.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings();
            int startInd =  array_listlastmodified .get(i).indexOf("(");

            int EndInd =  array_listlastmodified.get(i).indexOf("+") ;
            String createdDate =  array_listlastmodified.get(i).substring(startInd + 1, EndInd);
            long created1 = Long.parseLong(createdDate) + ro + dst;
            Date cDate = null;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));//TimeZone.getDefault());
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(created1)); 
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(created1);
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
            View itemView = new View(this);
            Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromUrl(array_listcreatoravatar.get(i));


            if(array_listmaintype.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("text"))
            {   
    itemView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.writescreenlowerparts, null);
    ImageView writescreenimageview=new ImageView(this);
    TextView writescreenposttext = new TextView(this);
    TextView writescreenusernametext = new TextView(this);
    TextView writescreendatetext=new TextView(this);
    TextView writescreensourcetext=new TextView(this);

    writescreensourcetext=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreensourcetext);
    writescreendatetext=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreendatetext);
    writescreenposttext=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenposttext);
    writescreenusernametext=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenusernametext);
    LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(MyEvents.width-90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
    writescreenposttext.setLayoutParams(param);




    if(array_listsource.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
    {
        writescreensourcetext.setText(" via mobile");
    }
    else
    {
        writescreensourcetext.setText("");
    }


    writescreenposttext.setText(""+array_listcontent.get(i));
    writescreenusernametext.setText(array_listcreatorname.get(i)+" at ");
    int thisHours = calendar.getTime().getHours();
            if (thisHours > 12)
             {


               thisHours = thisHours - 12;
              }
              String thisH = "" + thisHours;
             if (thisHours == 0)
                {
                 thisH = "00";
                }

              String amPM = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)== 0?"AM":"PM";

             if(calendar.getTime().getMinutes() < 10)
              {
            writescreendatetext.setText(thisH + ":0" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
              }
             else
              {
            writescreendatetext.setText(thisH + ":" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
               }
        Log.v("#############################",dateString );
        Log.v("----------------------", array_listcreatorname.get(i));
        writescreenimageview=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenimageview);
        writescreenimageview.setImageBitmap(bm);    
        if(isgrey==false)
               {
            TableRow tabttr1=new TableRow(this);
            tabttr1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topredline));
            tabttr1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            tl.addView(tabttr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }   
            }
         else if(array_listmaintype.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("image")) 
          {
         itemView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.writeimagelayout, null);
         TextView writescreencontent  =new TextView(this);
         TextView writescreenimagedatetext  =new TextView(this);
         TextView writescreenusernameimagetext  =new TextView(this);
         ImageView writescreenimagetypeimage=new ImageView(this);
         ImageView writescreenbigtypeimage=new ImageView(this);

         TextView writescreenimagesourcetext  =new TextView(this);

         writescreenimagesourcetext=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenimagesourcetext);
         if(array_listsource.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
         {
             writescreenimagesourcetext.setText(" via mobile");
         }
         else
         {
            writescreenimagesourcetext.setText("");
         }


         writescreencontent=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.writecaption);
         writescreenimagetypeimage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenimagetypeimage);

      writescreenbigtypeimage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenbigtypeimage);



                writescreenbigtypeimage.setTag(i);
                if(array_listcontent.get(i).length() > 1)
                {
                writescreencontent.setText(array_listcontent.get(i));
                }

                writescreenbigtypeimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        int j = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                        Intent in=new Intent(WriteScreen.this,FullImage.class);

                        fullimage= array_listimageurl.get(j);
                        Log.v("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%",array_listimageurl.get(j));
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                });

                writescreenusernameimagetext=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenusernameimagetext);
                writescreenimagedatetext=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenimagedatetext);
                writescreenusernameimagetext.setText(array_listcreatorname.get(i)+ " at ");


            int thisHours = calendar.getTime().getHours();
             if (thisHours > 12)
             {
                 thisHours = thisHours - 12;
            }
             String thisH = "" + thisHours;
             if (thisHours == 0)
             {
                 thisH = "00";
             }

                String amPM = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)== 0?"AM":"PM";
           //  myeventstime1.setText(cDate.toGMTString().substring(cDate.toGMTString().indexOf(":")-3).trim());
           if(calendar.getTime().getMinutes() < 10)
           {
               writescreenimagedatetext.setText(thisH + ":0" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
           }
           else
           {
               writescreenimagedatetext.setText(thisH + ":" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
           }
                String s = array_listimageurl.get(i);
                Bitmap bm1 = getBitmapFromUrl(s);
                writescreenimagetypeimage.setImageBitmap(bm);
                writescreenbigtypeimage.setLayoutParams(lpImageView);
                writescreenbigtypeimage.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            if(isgrey==false)
            {
                TableRow tabttr1=new TableRow(this);
                tabttr1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topredline));
                tabttr1.setLayoutParams(lp);
                tl.addView(tabttr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }   
            }


           else if(array_listmaintype.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("video")) 
            {
            itemView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.writescreenvideo, null);
            ImageView writescreenimagesmallvideotype=new ImageView(this);
            ImageView writescreenbigvideotype=new ImageView(this);
            TextView  writescreencontentvideotype =new TextView(this);
            TextView  writescreenusernamevideotype =new TextView(this);
            TextView writescreendateandtimevideotype  =new TextView(this);

            TextView writescreensourcevideotype =new TextView(this);

            writescreensourcevideotype=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreensourcevideotype);
             if(array_listsource.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
             {
                writescreensourcevideotype.setText(" via mobile");
             }
             else
             {
                writescreensourcevideotype.setText("");
             }




            writescreenimagesmallvideotype=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenimagesmallvideotype);
            writescreenbigvideotype=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenbigvideotype);

            writescreencontentvideotype=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreencontentvideotype);
            writescreenusernamevideotype=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenusernamevideotype);
            writescreendateandtimevideotype =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreendateandtimevideotype);

             writescreencontentvideotype.setText(array_listcontent.get(i));
            writescreenusernamevideotype.setText(array_listcreatorname.get(i)+" at ");


            int thisHours = calendar.getTime().getHours();
             if (thisHours > 12)
             {
                 thisHours = thisHours - 12;
            }
             String thisH = "" + thisHours;
             if (thisHours == 0)
             {
                 thisH = "00";
             }
             String amPM = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)== 0?"AM":"PM";

           if(calendar.getTime().getMinutes() < 10)
           {
               writescreendateandtimevideotype.setText(thisH + ":0" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
           }
           else
           {
               writescreendateandtimevideotype.setText(thisH + ":" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
           }
            writescreenimagesmallvideotype.setImageBitmap(bm); 
            String s1 =  array_listurl1.get(i);
            Bitmap bm2 = getBitmapFromUrl(s1);
            writescreenbigvideotype.setLayoutParams(lpImageView);
            writescreenbigvideotype.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            writescreenbigvideotype.setTag(i);
            writescreenbigvideotype.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int j = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                    Intent in=new Intent(WriteScreen.this,WatchVideo.class);
                    in.putExtra("path", array_listurl.get(j));
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });

            if(isgrey==false)
            {
                TableRow tabttr1=new TableRow(this);
                tabttr1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topredline));
                tabttr1.setLayoutParams(lp);
                tl.addView(tabttr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }   

            }
         else if(array_listmaintype.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("audio")) 
         {
             itemView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.writescreenaudio, null);
             ImageView writescreenimagesmallaudiotype=new ImageView(this);
             ImageButton writescreenbuttonaudioplay =new ImageButton(this);
             TextView  writescreencontentaudiotype =new TextView(this);
             TextView writescreenusernameaudiotype   =new TextView(this);
             //TextView writescreendateandtimeaudiotype =new TextView(this);
             ImageButton writescreenbuttonaudiostop =new ImageButton(this);
             TextView writescreendurationaudiotype   =new TextView(this);
             TextView writescreendtimeaudiotype   =new TextView(this);
             TextView writescreensourceaudiotype  =new TextView(this);

            writescreenbuttonaudiostop=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenbuttonaudiostop);
             writescreensourceaudiotype=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreensourceaudiotype);

             if(array_listsource.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
             {
             writescreensourceaudiotype.setText(" via mobile");
             }
             else
             {
            writescreensourceaudiotype.setText("");
            }

            writescreendurationaudiotype=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreendurationaudiotype);


                writescreendurationaudiotype.setText(array_listaudiodurationurl.get(i)); 
                writescreenbuttonaudioplay=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenbuttonaudioplay);
            writescreenbuttonaudioplay.setTag(i);
            writescreenbuttonaudioplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    int j = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                    String path=array_listaudiourl.get(j);
                     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try 
                    {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    } 
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try 
                    {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } 
                    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
                    {   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
                    {   
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer paramMediaPlayer) 
                        {   
                             mediaPlayer.stop();
                        }
                    }); 
                }   
            });
            writescreenbuttonaudiostop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View paramView) 
                {       
                    if(mediaPlayer!=null&& mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                }
            });
                writescreenimagesmallaudiotype=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenimagesmallaudiotype);       
                writescreenimagesmallaudiotype.setImageBitmap(bm);

                writescreencontentaudiotype=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreencontentaudiotype); 
                writescreencontentaudiotype.setText(array_listcontent.get(i));

                writescreenusernameaudiotype=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenusernameaudiotype);   
                writescreenusernameaudiotype.setText(array_listcreatorname.get(i)+" at ");

                writescreenbuttonaudiostop=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreenbuttonaudiostop);


                writescreendtimeaudiotype=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.writescreendtimeaudiotype);
                int thisHours = calendar.getTime().getHours();
                 if (thisHours > 12)
                 {
                     thisHours = thisHours - 12;
                }
                 String thisH = "" + thisHours;
                 if (thisHours == 0)
                 {
                     thisH = "00";
                 }
                 String amPM = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)== 0?"AM":"PM";
               //  myeventstime1.setText(cDate.toGMTString().substring(cDate.toGMTString().indexOf(":")-3).trim());
               if(calendar.getTime().getMinutes() < 10)
               {
                   writescreendtimeaudiotype.setText(thisH + ":0" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
               }
               else

               {
                   writescreendtimeaudiotype.setText(thisH + ":" + calendar.getTime().getMinutes() + " " + amPM);
               }
               if(isgrey==false)
                {
                    TableRow tabttr1=new TableRow(this);
                    tabttr1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topredline));
                    tabttr1.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tl.addView(tabttr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }          
         }
           tr.addView(itemView);
           tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

           isgrey=false;
        }
         }  
    }

    public Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(String url)
    {
        try{
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"img");
            return d;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        return null;
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String url)
    {
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;    
        httpRequest = new HttpGet(url); 
        Log.v("----------------------", url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpResponse response = null;
            try 
            {
        response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

            }           
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {

            e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = null;
        try 
        {
            bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity (entity);
        }    
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        InputStream instream = null;
        try 
        {
            instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
        }    
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream); 
        return bm;
    }

    public void writescreen() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
    {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         String un = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(username.getBytes("UTF-8"),android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
         String ps = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(password.getBytes("UTF-8"),android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
          AuthScope as = new AuthScope(hostSecure,443);
          UsernamePasswordCredentials upc = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(un,ps);
          String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"),android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
          ((AbstractHttpClient) client).getCredentialsProvider() .setCredentials(as, upc);
          BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
          BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
          localContext.setAttribute("preemptive-auth", basicAuth);
          HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(hostSecure, 443, "https");
          HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://apiv1secure.somedomain.com/event/"+eId+"/page?Token=RCFB3m4W"+ "&format=json");
          httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ auth);
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, httpget, localContext);
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          Object content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
          Log.e("", "----------------------------------------"+content);
          json = new JSONObject(content.toString());


          JSONArray s = null;  

          s = json.getJSONArray("Posts");   

          for(int i = 0; i< s.length();i++)
         {
                 String a = s.getString(i);
                 JSONObject jt = new JSONObject(a);
                 String  postid=jt.getString("Id");
                 if(jt.has("Content"))
                 {
                    String  postcontent=jt.getString("Content"); 
                     array_listcontent.add(postcontent);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     array_listcontent.add("");
                 }

                 String creator = jt.getString("Creator");
                 array_listid.add(postid);

                 JSONObject jt1 = new JSONObject(creator);
                 String creatorid = jt1.getString("Id");
                 String creatoravatar=jt1.getString("Avatar");
                 String creatorname=jt1.getString("Name");
                 array_listcreatorname.add(creatorname);
                 array_listcreatorid.add(creatorid);
                 array_listcreatoravatar.add(creatoravatar);

                 mainType=jt.getString("Type");
                 array_listmaintype.add(mainType);

                 lastmodified=jt.getString("LastModified");
                 array_listlastmodified.add(lastmodified);

                String createddate=jt.getString("Created");
                array_listcreated .add(createddate);

                source=jt.getString("Source");
                 array_listsource.add(source);




                if(mainType.equalsIgnoreCase("image"))
                {
                    String Media = "";

                    if(jt.has("Media"))
                    {
                     JSONArray mediatype =  jt.getJSONArray("Media");  
                     String d = mediatype.getString(0);
                     JSONObject jmediatype = new JSONObject(d);
                     d = mediatype.getString(0);
                     jmediatype = new JSONObject(d);
                      imagetype = jmediatype.getString("Type");
                     String imageurl=jmediatype.getString("Url");
                     array_listimagetype.add(imagetype);
                     array_listimageurl.add(imageurl);
                     array_listtype1.add("0");
                     array_listurl1.add("0");
                     array_listduration.add("0");
                     array_listurl.add("0");
                     array_listtype.add("0");
                    array_listaudiourl.add("0");
                    array_listaudiodurationurl.add("0");
                    }
                }
                else if (mainType.equalsIgnoreCase("video"))
                {
                    String Media = "";
                    if(jt.has("Media"))
            {
                     JSONArray mediatype=  jt.getJSONArray("Media");  
                     String d = mediatype.getString(0);
                     JSONObject jmediatype = new JSONObject(d);
                     String  type=jmediatype.getString("Type");
                     String  url=jmediatype.getString("Url");
                     String durationtype=jmediatype.getString("Duration");
                     array_listduration.add(durationtype);
                     array_listurl.add(url);
                     array_listtype.add(type);

                     d = mediatype.getString(1);
                     jmediatype = new JSONObject(d);
                     String type1 = jmediatype.getString("Type");
                     String url1=jmediatype.getString("Url");
                     array_listtype1.add(type1);
                     array_listurl1.add(url1);

                     array_listimagetype.add("0");
                     array_listimageurl.add("0");
                    array_listaudiourl.add("0");
                    array_listaudiodurationurl.add("0");
                    }
                }
                else if (mainType.equalsIgnoreCase("text"))
                {
                     array_listimagetype.add("0");
                     array_listimageurl.add("0");
                     array_listtype1.add("0");
                     array_listurl1.add("0");
                     array_listduration.add("0");
                     array_listurl.add("0");
                     array_listtype.add("0");
                    array_listaudiourl.add("0");
                    array_listaudiodurationurl.add("0");
                }
                else if(mainType.equalsIgnoreCase("audio"))
                {
                    JSONArray mediatype=  jt.getJSONArray("Media");  
                     String d = mediatype.getString(0);
                     JSONObject jmediatype = new JSONObject(d);
                     String  audiourl=jmediatype.getString("Url");
                     String audioduration=jmediatype.getString("Duration");
                     array_listaudiourl.add(audiourl);
                     array_listaudiodurationurl.add(audioduration);

                     array_listimagetype.add("0");
                     array_listimageurl.add("0");
                     array_listtype1.add("0");
                     array_listurl1.add("0");
                     array_listduration.add("0");
                     array_listurl.add("0");
                     array_listtype.add("0");

                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? IMO it would not work because resources are preprocessed (for performance reasons) and stored in apk in some binary form.

Comment: You are wrong. I have made an app complete dynamic loading (reason being too many resources were making apk size more than 50MB). You shouldn't vote down, if you are not sure answer is not correct.

Comment: OK. Show me some code that loads a simple layout xml from network (not only images, etc..). Add it to your answer and I'll upvote you.

Comment: Please let me know, If I need to provide any more details to explain my point.

Comment: I have just given proof of concept in above code. In my case, above code was efficient. It depends on the content and your resources to download from online server. You can also try LazyLoading to have better performing code.

Comment: I can seem to remove a -1. Please briefly edit your answer (change a character or so).

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) clearly states that (3rd paragraph).

You can, however, load bitmaps and text from network and inject them by hand. But, you *can not* load and inflate layout resources.

Comment: The OP states "can load all the resources from online". You can not load all the resources, most importantly the main part: the layout resources. Nor can you inflate local resources so that they use external resources (loaded from network). What you propose is obvious: inflate an internal resource and set all properties and external resources by hand. IMO, this is not what OP asked. I provided the same answer. Anyhow, you fully stated this in your primary answer and I did not read it properly, so I'm removing -1. But you do not deserve a +1.

Comment: @Shourab: ahh, yes, and thank you for -1 on a correct answer. Or was I wrong at some point?

Comment: And btw, promise was to "show me code that loads a simple layout xml from network (not only images, etc..)". Did you do that? No

Comment: Peter I have written in my answer that  "(I guess, text and images is your requirement) " so it could be my guess wrong but not the answer. By the developer's reply who has asked the question, it seems like I have interpreted the question correctly. Also your understanding of question was different than me, I am removing my vote down.

Comment: SO says, you need to edit the answer so that I can remove my votedown.